# How to access annotation variables from interceptor

Tags: java, annotations, interceptor

Lets say I have simple annotation

```
@InterceptorBinding 
@Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface CheckUserRole {
    @Nonbinding String[] allowedRoles() default "";
}
```

Next, I have interceptor defined like this:

```
@Interceptor
@CheckUserRole
public class CheckUserRoleInterceptor
```

How can I access `allowedRoles` from annotation? I'm doing it this way:

```
CheckUserRole checkUserRoleAnnotation = ctx.getMethod().getAnnotation(CheckUserRole.class);

if(checkUserRoleAnnotation != null){
     String[] allowedRoles = checkUserRoleAnnotation.allowedRoles();
}
```

But this only works if I use annotation on method in my class. If I want to use my annotation on whole class, `checkUserRoleAnnotation` is `null`, since my method ins't annotated in code with it.

How can I access those variables when whole class is annotated?

Comment: You can access it in a class that is handling the annotation, not in the class on which you put the annotation itself. @Constraint(validatedBy = Validator.class) -> in the Validator.java file, you'll be able to access the members of the annotation

Comment: I mean I want to access it in interceptor. Maybe I didn't explain it well. I have class `ExampleClass` and `void exampleMethod()` in this class. When I annotate `exampleMethod()`, I can access variable in interceptor (the way described above), but when I annotate `ExampleClass` with it, all method should be annotated, but it returns `null`.

Comment: yes, I got that. so what is stopping you from adding @Constraint(validatedBy = CheckUserRoleInterceptor.class) to your annotation?

Comment: Can you explain this, please? When I add `@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckUserRoleInterceptor.class)` to `public @interface CheckUserRole`, it requires me to extend `ConstraintValidator`. I've never used validators, so I don't really know, how can I access variable from there.

Comment: there may be some other ways to do it, but what exactly do you want it for, if not for validation?

Comment: This should be interceptor. The interceptor checks if user has access to this method by iterating over allowed roles - it happens just before this method is fired. I need to access allowed roles variable in order to check if user has one of them. (AOP based on this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/cdi-aop - `@Secure`)

Comment: so, you "validate" the role(s) of the user. I don't see why extending a ConstraintValidator is such a problem. extend it, implement it's methods, and chances are, you'll be able to pick it up quite fast.

Comment: I wanted to avoid extending it since I extend from another class that have 'general methods'. But still, I'll give it a try and check if it will work, thanks for info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found good solution for this problem. To access annotation from method or class (if there is no annotation on method level) just use my function:

```
// Returns annotation from method or class (if does not exist, returns null)
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
protected Object getAnnotationClass(Class clazz, InvocationContext ctx){
    Object annotationClass = ctx.getMethod().getAnnotation(clazz);

    // Try to find annotation on class level
    if(annotationClass == null){
        annotationClass = ctx.getTarget().getClass().getSuperclass().getAnnotation(clazz);
    }

    return annotationClass;
}
```

My function does:

1. Check if there is annotation on method level
2. If not, check if there is annotation on class level
3. If still not, return null

Note using `.getSuperclass()` since `.getClass()` returns proxy.

Example of usage:

```
CheckUserRole annotationClass = (CheckUserRole) getAnnotationClass(CheckUserRole.class, ctx);   

if(annotationClass != null){
    String[] allowedRoles = annotationClass.allowedRoles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

@Context
ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

in your interceptor class.With ResourceInfo object you will be able to get associated class as well as method(and other useful info).

after that use 
Annotationabc abc = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Annotationabc .class)
to get the annotation on top of ur method